# How to query objects through a Pointer using REST API?

Tags: rest, parse-platform

I have this structure hosted on parse.com:

**Event**

- objectId: `String`
- playerId: `Pointer<Player>`
- matchId: `Pointer<Match>`
- *some other properties not relevant to the question*

**Match**

- objectId: `String`
- ownerId: `String`
- matchDate: `Date`

I want to retrieve all events related to one specific Match using REST, but there is something wrong with the query I'm using.

This is the query I'm using (ruby with HTTParty gem):

```
base_uri = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes"
endpoint = 'Event/?&include=matchId&where={"ownerId":"201"}'
app_id = "app_id"
rest_api_key = "api_key"
headers = {"X-Parse-Application-Id" => app_id, 
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" => rest_api_key, 
    "Content-Type" => "application/json"}

response = HTTParty.get(URI.encode("#{base_uri}/#{endpoint}"), headers: headers)
```

Comment: Afaik. currently there is no standard way or even recommendation to describe queries. There are non-standard solutions like the one you found, or e.g. https://github.com/persvr/rql . The only general standard solution I know of, is describing a query param with JSON-LD, hydra and URI templates and put SPARQL into that param. Afaik there is no RDF vocab, which can describe queries. Maybe I'll make one, but I won't have time to do this for months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that it's done the same way as [relational queries](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#relational-queries). Here is the working query:

```
endpoint = 'Event/?where={"matchId":{"$inQuery":{"where":{"ownerId":201},"className":"Match"}}}'
```